# How to trigger tests related to a particular file on Scala SBT

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, tdd

I'm a JS developer and I'm learning Scala, I'm used to the Jest test framework, in JS, which allows you to watch changed files and run tests for the changed modules.

Is there something similar in Scala?

I know that I can do:

**~test** to watch all the files and trigger all the tests

**~test package/test_class** to watch all the files and trigger only the specified test class.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`testQuick`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html#testQuick):

> The `testQuick` task, like `testOnly`, allows to filter the tests to run to specific tests or wildcards using the same syntax to indicate the filters. In addition to the explicit filter, only the tests that satisfy one of the following conditions are run:
>
> - The tests that failed in the previous run
> - The tests that were not run before
> - The tests that have one or more transitive dependencies, maybe in a different project, recompiled.

You can use it with `~` and filtering that you already know.